# How to use http-request redirect or http-request set-path in HAproxy?

Tags: haproxy

I am a newb to HAProxy, and am bashing my head against this one. I’m trying to set up what I think is a fairly simple exercise in mapping applications listening on various ports to specific URLs.Like if my app page-designer is listening at http://IP:30000,then i would like to map it to http://IP/page-designer.I know i have asked a similar question before.But this time, the question is actually a little different.Upon doing some research,I heard that this can be done using http-request redirect or by adding reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /page-designer(.*)  \1\ \2 in the backend.

haproxy.cfg

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind 206.189.22.155:80

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i /page-designer
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:30000
```

hitting http://206.189.22.155:30000 shows me the apache tomcat homepage.But hitting http://206.189.22.155/page-designer shows me "HTTP Status 404 - /page-designer the requested resource is not available".So how should i modify my haproxy.cfg to use http-request redirect or http-request set-path to rewrite the requested path.I have also tried this with another node js app running on port 5000,but that time instead of 404 error i was getting "Cannot GET /page-designer".So i am sure what is actually going wrong here.Plz help?

Comment: is this the only page/purpose you host with ha proxy? if yes nginx is easier to config in my point of View...

Comment: no actually this is not the only page and i want to use only haproxy for this!!

Answer (score 1):

In your backend, use

```
http-request set-path %[path,regsub(/page-designer(.*),\1)]
```

This should do a regexp substitution to remove `/page-designer` from your path